# A question about the Spring Framework 6.0.8 reference documentation。

Tags: spring

A note about modules: Spring’s framework jars allow for deployment to JDK 9’s module path ("Jigsaw"). For use in Jigsaw-enabled applications, the Spring Framework 5 jars come with "Automatic-Module-Name" manifest entries which define stable language-level module names ("spring.core", "spring.context", etc.) independent from jar artifact names (the jars follow the same naming pattern with "-" instead of ".", e.g. "spring-core" and "spring-context"). Of course, Spring’s framework jars keep working fine on the classpath on both JDK 8 and 9+.

Why is Spring Framework 5 not Spring Framework 6 in the above paragraph.
The reference document I looked at was Spring Framework 6.

Because I read the documentation of 6, I think it should be Spring Framework 6, so I am looking for an answer.